# Conditions for a sheaf over a basis to be isomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given two sheaves $\mathscr F,\mathscr G$ over a top. space $X$, consider an open covering $X=\cup_{\lambda\in L} U_\lambda$, then if $\mathscr F|_{U_\lambda}=\mathscr G|_{U_\lambda}$ for all $\lambda\in L$, we have that $\mathscr F=\mathscr G$.

I know this isn't true if we consider $\mathscr F(U_\lambda)$ and $\mathscr G(U_\lambda)$ instead, there are many counterexamples, even on this website itself.

But I haven't seen the case with the restriction. I think this is what's talked about on section 3.3.2 of EGA 0 (https://fppf.site/ega/ega0-auto.pdf here's an English version of the text), but I don't understand Grothendieck's proof (if he's proving what I'm asking, of course).

Is he saying that, because the diagram is commutative, we've got a bijection $u_\lambda:\mathscr F_\lambda\cong\mathscr G_\lambda$ and we can take the collection of $(u_\lambda)$ to be $u:\mathscr F\cong\mathscr G$

I also thought about taking a section $s$ over $\mathscr F(U)$, then a covering of each $U$ by $V_i$, that'd give us some section $t|_{V_i}$ that we can move to $\mathscr G(U)$ and paste them there, obtaining some section $s'$, and doing the same but swapping $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G$ would give us an isomorphism.

Cheers!

Comment: Your statement is false: consider $\Bbb P^1_k$ with the standard open cover by two copies of $\Bbb A^1_k$ and the sheaves $\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O}(1)$. Your question also needs improvement: questions should be self-contained, and omitting the text of EGA that you're dealing with (which contains important details!) will make it less likely for you to attract answers and more likely to attract closed votes.

Comment: I added a link to EGA's chapter 0.$\\$


Thanks a lot for the counterexample too, I didn't even think that checking the projective line would be enough. Just for clarification, $\mathscr O(1)$ is the twist  sheaf I guess, but what'd be the $\mathscr O$ alone in this case? Sorry if these last two questions are super dumb. 
Replacing the equality by isomorphism wouldn't change anything, right?


If you want, please the comment as an answer so I can mark it as responded.

Comment: The statement is false, and its falsehood is essentially the reason some people want to look at stacks, and other higher-categorical notions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was going to be a comment but it becomes to long.

If you have an *equality* $\mathscr{F}|_{U_\lambda}=\mathscr{G}|_{U_\lambda}$ for each $\lambda$ then you have $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}$. Indeed, given an open set $V$ and $s \in\mathscr{F}(V)$ you have $$s_\lambda:=s|_{V\cap {U_\lambda}}\in \mathscr{F}(V\cap U_\lambda)=\mathscr{G}(V\cap U_\lambda)$$ for all $\lambda$ and this $s_\lambda$ are compatible together as sections of  $\mathscr{G}$ hence you can glue them together to a section $s'\in \mathscr{G}(V)$. Then the map $s\mapsto s'$ gives you the isomorphism.

What is not true is that $\mathscr{F}|_{U_\lambda}\cong\mathscr{G}|_{U_\lambda}$ for each $\lambda$ implies $\mathscr{F}\cong\mathscr{G}$ and the reason way this is not a contradiction with the above is because this isomorphisms for different lambda may not induce the same isomorphisms in the intersections $\mathscr{F}|_{U_\lambda\cap U_\delta}\cong\mathscr{G}|_{U_\lambda\cap U_\delta}$. Hence, in the proof above we may not have that the image of $s_\lambda$ in $\mathscr{G}(V\cap U_\lambda)$ are compatible between them over $V\cap U_\lambda\cap U_\delta$. As two set that are equal always have only one equality map between them, the isomorphisms given by equalities are trivially compatible.

The compatibility issue of the isomorphisms is the only obstruction to get the global isomorphisms though and this is what is written in the chapter of EGA as KReiser explained.

Comment: I agree that a literal equality (all of the sets of sections have the exact same elements, etc) on an open cover would produce a literal equality of sheaves (this gets around the problem of not having a map because the identity map of sets turns out to be a morphism of sheaves, and then one can check that it's an isomorphism on an open cover, etc etc). But one almost never has literal equalities in algebra. For instance, $\{0\}$ is not equal to $\{\}$ but both are isomorphic to the zero module. I took the OP's use of "=" to mean "an isomorphism", which is a frequent occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $\Bbb P^1_k$ with the standard affine open cover $\Bbb P^1_k =U_0,U_1$ by two copies of $\Bbb A^1_k$, with the sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}(1)$. Then the restrictions of both of these sheaves to the standard affine opens are just $\mathcal{O}_{U_i}$, but $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}\not\cong \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1_k}(1)$.

What's going on in the linked section of EGA is that Grothendieck is explaining how to glue a morphism of sheaves together: if we have two sheaves $\mathcal{F,G}$ on a space $X$  with values in a nice enough category and an open cover $\{U_\lambda\}$ of $X$, then if we have morphisms $\mathcal{F}|_{U_\lambda}\to\mathcal{G}|_{U_\lambda}$ which satisfy a compatibility condition, then these morphisms glue to a global morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$. So your reading of this section of text was not quite correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the counterexample, the clarifications and for explaining what I misunderstood!