# Not every locally free module of fixed rank is free

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying some scheme theory and commutative algebra, and the silly question in the title came to my mind [while reading this on the StacksProject](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFW).

More specifically: let $A$ be a (commutative, with unity) ring and $M$ and $A$-module. We say that $M$ is a *locally free module of rank r* if there exists a family $\{f_i\}_{i=0}^n \in A$ such that $\text{Spec(A)} = \bigcup_{i=0}^n D(f_i)$ and $\widetilde{M}|_{D(f_i)} \cong \bigoplus^r \widetilde{A}|_{D(f_i)}$, where we let $\widetilde{M}$ be the $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}{A}}$-module associated to $M$.

From my understanding, not every locally free module of rank $r$ must be free of rank $r$ (indeed, if not, every Picard group of any ring would be trivial), but what goes wrong with the following reasoning? On the open cover $\{D(f_i)\}_i$ we have
$$
\widetilde{M}|_{D(f_i)} \cong \widetilde{M_{f_i}} \cong \widetilde{\bigoplus^r A_{f_i}} \cong \bigoplus^r\widetilde{ A_{f_i}} \cong \bigoplus^r\widetilde{ A}|_{D(f_i)} \cong (\widetilde{\bigoplus^r A})|_{D(f_i)},
$$
hence by glueing the sheaves we get $\widetilde{M} \cong \widetilde{\bigoplus^r A}$ and then $M \cong \bigoplus^r A$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've forgotten that gluing also requires you to track the isomorphisms and they must be compatible. This is probably a duplicate many times over, let me see if I can find an appropriate duplicate target.

Comment: How about the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659402/conditions-for-a-sheaf-over-a-basis-to-be-isomorphic) - does that answer your question?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, thanks! I've completely overlooked it in my argument.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help.